# Is "cat /tmp/healthy" the only way to configure a Kubernetes command probe?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to understand exactly how kubernetes command probes work, but the documentation is quite dry on this.

Every example I found on kubernetes command probes gives the same kind of code:

```
livenessProbe:
    exec:
      command:
      - cat
      - /tmp/healthy
```

I seems possible to pass any command to the exec object. So my question is:

1. What would be other good examples of probes commands?
2. How will kubernetes determine if the result of the command is a success or a failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any command as an `exec` probe.

The healthy of the container is [determined by the exit code](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command). If the command succeeds, it returns `0`, and the `kubelet` considers the Container to be alive and healthy. Anything different than exit code `0` is considered unhealthy.

Some applications provide binaries/scripts that are made for health checks.

Examples:

- [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/6b3367d471b789900526a0e2ecc0bafa8aeb4d5a/stable/rabbitmq/templates/statefulset.yaml#L152): Provides the `rabbitmq-api-check`
- [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/6b3367d471b789900526a0e2ecc0bafa8aeb4d5a/stable/postgresql/templates/statefulset.yaml#L175): Provides the `pg_isready`
- [MySQL](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/6b3367d471b789900526a0e2ecc0bafa8aeb4d5a/stable/mysql/templates/deployment.yaml#L120): Provides the `mysqladmin ping`

The use of `exec` probe is also useful when you need to define an entire script with the logic of your expected healthiness.

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually `cat` is one good exec command probe. But any linux command is valid.
2. kubelet will check on the exit code ($?). 0 is healthy. Anything else is unhealthy.